# To display float point image in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am getting a float point image in the range of 0 to 1. I tried to display this float image in Qt using label but it didn't work.
I checked the QImage formats and found that Qt don't support float image. now i am trying it in this way..

```
            QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
            colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));
             Mat img2;
            DepthImg.convertTo(img2, CV_8UC1);
            assert(img2.isContinuous());
            QImage image = QImage((unsigned char*)(img2.data), DepthImg.cols, DepthImg.rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
            image.setColorTable(colorTable);
            ui.ThreeD->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image, Qt::AutoColor));
            ui.ThreeD->setScaledContents(true);
            qApp->processEvents();
            this->ui.ThreeD->show();
```

Here "DepthImage" is a float point image.

```
 Mat img2;
 DepthImg.convertTo(img2, CV_8UC1);
 assert(img2.isContinuous());
 QImage image = QImage((unsigned char*)img2.data, img2.cols, img2.rows, img2.cols*3, QImage::Format_RGB888);
 ui.ThreeD->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image, Qt::AutoColor));
 ui.ThreeD->setScaledContents(true);
 qApp->processEvents();
 this->ui.ThreeD->show();
```

After executing it in both ways i am getting only a black image.
Can any body help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need scale image by factor 255.
You can do it by changing

```
DepthImg.convertTo(img2, CV_8UC1);
```

with

```
DepthImg.convertTo(img2, CV_8UC1, 255.0);
```